# How to use swagger to create RESTful API

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, swagger

Using swagger (edit mode), I created a project template that contains `swagger.yaml` (see the figure below):

[image]

Then I opened this template in IntellijIDEA in order to start developing a backend for 3 endpoints that I specified in `swagger.yaml`. My goal is to develop RESTful API with several endpoints.

I quite misunderstand the generated structure of the project. Usually there is `src` with `main` and `test`. In this project's structure I see folders like `express`, `should`, etc. What do they mean? And how actually can I convert this project into Spring MVC (that uses spring-boot)? Should I manually add `pom.xml`? Or the spring project's structure can be generated automatically from Swagger?

Comment: That's not Java, Spring, or Maven.  That's Javascript using NPM and setup for building an express server in NodeJS.  I'm guessing you probably generated the wrong type of project -- it's a "Swagger" project for NodeJS/Express not for Java/Spring.

Edit: Btw the "node_modules" and everything under it is essentially the NPM equivalent of a local Maven repository.

Comment: @kab: Should I open swagger ui and regenerate it for Java/Spring?

Comment: If that's what you used and you want a Java/Spring project then yes.  I don't use Swagger and can't stand it so I have no experience with any of their tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand what what folders like `express` mean, you will need to study the [MEAN Stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEAN_%28software_bundle%29). This is a good starting point.

Now, coming to your problem. I think you have two options here -

1. Feed the `swagger.yaml` that you have to the [online swagger editor](http://editor.swagger.io/) and Generate Server for Spring MVC. Not `node.js` .
2. Use the existing project that you have and convert it to Spring. As a general direction, it would involve following steps:

   i) Examine the contents of `package.json` . It would have a list of dependencies

   ii) Find the `Maven` equivalents of these dependencies and create a `pom.xml` .

   iii) Create a web project and deploy it on a server.